# Resize in textview when I scroll in customized MotionLayout

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I have following project in Github : https://github.com/AliRezaeiii/TMDb-Paging

Here is my person_header layout file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="person"
            type="com.sample.android.tmdb.ui.person.PersonWrapper" />

    </data>

    <com.sample.android.tmdb.widget.CollapsibleToolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layoutDescription="@xml/scene_person_header"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed"
        tools:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        tools:maxHeight="320dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_background"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:imageUrl="@{@string/base_backdrop_path(person.backdropPath)}"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.38"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/icon_background"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/window_background"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tileable_edge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30px"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/tileable_edge"
            android:tint="@color/window_background"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/icon_background"
            tools:ignore="PxUsage,contentDescription" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/back_frame"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/padding_micro"
            tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_padded"
                android:transitionName="@string/transition_search_back"
                tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="162dp"
            android:layout_height="41dp"
            android:text="@{person.personName}"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            tools:text="Ali Rezaei" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/icon_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                app:civ_border_color="@android:color/white"
                app:civ_border_width="2dp"
                app:profileUrl="@{person.profilePath}"
                tools:src="@drawable/ic_error_outline_black_36dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guideline"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.67" />

    </com.sample.android.tmdb.widget.CollapsibleToolbar>

</layout>
```

CollapsibleToolbar is extending MotionLayout :

```
class CollapsibleToolbar @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : MotionLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr), AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {

    override fun onOffsetChanged(appBarLayout: AppBarLayout?, verticalOffset: Int) {
        progress = -verticalOffset / appBarLayout?.totalScrollRange?.toFloat()!!
    }

    override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow()
        (parent as? AppBarLayout)?.addOnOffsetChangedListener(this)
    }
}
```

And here is `scene_person_header` xml file :

```
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
        motion:duration="1000"
        motion:interpolator="linear">

        <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">

            <Constraint
                android:id="@id/image_background"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.38" />

            <Constraint
                android:id="@id/icon_background"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/window_background"
                motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline" />

            <Constraint
                android:id="@id/name"
                android:layout_width="162dp"
                android:layout_height="41dp"
                motion:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <Constraint
                android:id="@id/icon_layout"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                motion:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/name"
                motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.24000001"
                motion:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

            <Constraint
                android:id="@id/back_frame"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </ConstraintSet>

        <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
            <Constraint
                android:id="@id/image_background"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.38" />

            <Constraint
                android:id="@id/icon_background"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline" />

            <Constraint
                android:id="@id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="28dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/back_frame" />

            <Constraint
                android:id="@id/icon_layout"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

            <Constraint
                android:id="@id/back_frame"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

        </ConstraintSet>

    </Transition>

</MotionScene>
```

When I launch PersonActivity, the name of character is shown as bellow image :

[image]

As soon as I start to scroll in PersonActivity, name of character resizes and is shown as bellow image :

[image]

What should I do to have initial size of `name` as the initial size of motionLayout start scrolling? Is there any changes I should make here :

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="162dp"
                android:layout_height="41dp"
                android:text="@{person.personName}"
                app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
                tools:text="Ali Rezaei" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find issue tracking at : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155215198